# Reduced-pressure (vacuum) evaporation/drying of 15 liters of aqueous solution

Tags: everyday-chemistry, water, solutions

I have **15 liters of aqueous solution** inside an aluminum stock pot which rests upon a hot plate. I want to **reduce the boiling point from 150°C to 100°C using reduced pressure**.

What is the **most economical way efficiently to dry the solute**? Economical means does not require specialty equipment (i.e., laboratory vacuum pumps, expensive cold traps, etc.)?

I own a water aspirator pump (attaches to sink, 27.4 in Hg maximum vacuum, 6 liters/minute) and a 2-stage electric vacuum pump (15-micron, 3CFM) that I use for degassing epoxies. I don't know whether either of these will be of any use here.

Answer (score 2):

The aspirator pump would be unlikely to be damaged by the distillate (and can be cheaply repaired or replaced), but the electric vacuum pump likely will require a cold-trap to prevent the vapors from destroying it.

The aspirator pump would seem the way to go, but you must factor in the cost of water in your location. This [Nalgene aspirator](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003OBYNBO) uses ~6.5 liter/minute. A [recirculating aspirator pump](http://www.thomassci.com/Equipment/Pumps/Vacuum/_/A-1000S-Aspirator-Pumps) might be the best compromise for a production environment, where efficiency is important, and it might be feasible to save and recycle the distillate.